# How to get value by form input name through javascript when no formDd or inputID exists?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://localhost:4442/my-profile/updateField?1557" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="js-form--update-field-onchange " autocomplete="off"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="123456789">
```

And **without** changing the HTML, I want to retrieve the unique and rotating value `123456789` within `<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="123456789">`.

I was considering `getElementByName();` or `getElementById();`, however as seen in the above HTML. There is no `getElementByName();` or `getElementById();` reference within the input form. How can I go about retrieving this `_token` value in JavaScript?

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelector` for select the `input` element.

Try below code -

```js
var inputVal = document.querySelector('input[name=_token]').value;
console.log(inputVal);
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://localhost:4442/my-profile/updateField?1557" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="js-form--update-field-onchange " autocomplete="off"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="123456789">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('_token');
console.log(elem.value);
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="https://localhost:4442/my-profile/updateField?1557" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="js-form--update-field-onchange " autocomplete="off"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH"><input name="_token" id="_token" type="hidden" value="123456789">
```